# JavaScript User Agents API to fetch and filter by browser class type

Tags: javascript, api, user-agent

Is there any user agent retrieval API? So that to filter by browser class type, like `mobile`, `desktop`, `bot`, etc.
From [this web site](http://ua.theafh.net/) - that claims to have the largest database of User Agents, being collected since 2006,
I wrote this simple [tool](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/b4c1865c8414aa457ad1e344bb280212) to get User Agents from it (via the browser at this time):

```
function UserAgents () {
 var COL_UA=1; // for search results use 2
 var COL_CLASS=3; // for search results use 4
 this.list=[];
 this.Class='';
 this.parse = function(Class) {
  this.list=[];
  var self=this;
  this.Class=Class;
  $('tr').each(function(index,item) {
    var td=$(this).find('td');
    var uac=$( td[COL_CLASS] ).text();
    var ua = $( td[COL_UA] ).text()
    var regex = new RegExp(Class);
    if( regex.test(uac) ) { self.list.push(ua); }
  })
 }
 this.download = function() {
  if(this.list.length==0) return;
  var pp = document.createElement('a');
  pp.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify( this.list )));
  pp.setAttribute('download', "useragents_" + this.Class + ".txt");
  pp.click();
}
}
```

So from the console it's possible to query `mobile` user agents:

```
var ua=new UserAgents();
ua.parse('mobil');
ua.list
Array[400]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; LG-D855 Build/LRX21R.A1450702344; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/47.0.2526.100 Mobile Safari/537.36 ACHEETAHI/2100502020"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; D5103 Build/18.1.A.1.23) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.95 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

and for `desktop` user agents:

```
ua.list
Array[200]
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.50 (Edition Campaign 09)"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 AOL/9.8 AOLBuild/4346.2019.US Safari/537.36"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
```

or both `mobile` and `desktop`:

```
ua.parse('mobil|desktop')
ua.list
Array[600]
```

you can get `bot` user agents:

```
ua.parse('bot')
ua.list
Array[400]
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"baiduSpider"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:10.0.4) Gecko/10.0.4 Firefox/10.0.4 Fennec/10.0.4 slurp"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) Excel/14.59.0"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Nokia) like Gecko BingPreview/1.0b"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Image Hunter 2.5.0 (iPad; iPhone OS 6.1.3; en_US)"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Fetcher/0.1)"
ua.list[ Math.floor(Math.random() * ua.list.length) ]
"yacybot (/global; amd64 Linux 2.6.32-042stab108.2; java 1.7.0_91; America/en) http://yacy.net/bot.html"
```

As soon you parse a class type, you can grab them to file:

```
ua.download()
```

This will download a file named `useragents_classtype.txt` locally.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware of the CSV-Download button next to every search result there? So, what do you want exactly to achieve? A randomized “Top-List”? And by the way the oldest user agents are from 2001 ;-) http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22%2A%22&include=yes&class=all&do=asc

Comment: yes I know of the download button I was doing something on the array list before getting it.

Comment: one of the thing needed could be parsing of the `User-Agent` by OS, Version, Name, etc - like this api does: http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=Opera/9.70%20(Linux%20i686%20;%20U;%20en-us)%20Presto/2.2.0&getJSON=all