# Obtaining HTML source code with Python cookie

Tags: python, html, cookies

```
    import urllib

    #my url here stored as url

    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    print(htmltext)
```

I'm trying to get source code from a url

I get source code but it is from a different page saying two things;
please enable cookies and
this domain has banned your access based on your browser's signature

Is there any way that anyone knows of to get the source code when the browser knows your not actually on the page?

Comment: Try the Requests package http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies  Its easier than urllib

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set an url opener

```
def createOpener(self):
        handlers = []                                                       
        cj = MyCookieJar();
        cj.set_policy(cookielib.DefaultCookiePolicy(rfc2965=True))
        cjhdr = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
        handlers.append(cjhdr)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', self.getUserAgent()),
                                  ('Host', 'google.com')]
        return opener
```

where the cookie jar is

```
class MyCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar):
    def _cookie_from_cookie_tuple(self, tup, request):
        name, value, standard, rest = tup
        version = standard.get('version', None)
        if version is not None:
            version = version.replace('"', '')
            standard["version"] = version
        return cookielib.CookieJar._cookie_from_cookie_tuple(self, tup, request)
```

At this point you create the opener and fetch the data reading the url handler like:

```
def fetchURL(self, url, data=None, headers={}):
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
        self.opener = self.createOpener()
        urlHandle = self.opener.open(request)
        return urlHandle.read()
```

It's a good idea to have a `User-Agent` list and read from it:

```
with open(ffpath) as f:
    USER_AGENTS_LIST = f.read().splitlines()
```

and get a random one from it

```
index = random.randint(0,len(USER_AGENTS_LIST)-1)
uA=USER_AGENTS_LIST[index]
```

To have a list of user agent take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510058/javascript-user-agents-api-to-fetch-and-filter-by-browser-class-type).

This is just to have and idea to do this without any external framework.